# How to show an image next to text in Typst

Tags: typst

I want to show an image next to text using Typst, like this:

[image: Image next to text]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the developers, [it can't be done](https://github.com/typst/typst/discussions/2832) [yet](https://github.com/typst/typst/discussions/1069). They say this feature is on the development roadmap.

On the other hand there is a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/lkndl/typst-bioinfo-thesis) which claims to implement basic wrapfig functionality. So that might work to some extent.

Answer (score 3):

[wrap-it](https://github.com/ntjess/wrap-it/) can do this (full docs [here](https://github.com/ntjess/wrap-it/blob/main/docs/manual.pdf))

Example (tested on Typst.app's online editor and also in VSCode with the extensions Typst LSP (to save as PDF) and Typst Preview (for instant preview as you type)):

```
#import "@preview/wrap-it:0.1.0": wrap-content

#set par(
  justify: true //to make text flow nicer around image
)

#let fig = [#figure(
  rect(fill: teal, radius: 0.5em, width: 8em),
  caption: [A figure],
) <tealrect>] //must use square brackets for @tealrect reference in the following text to work, since currently Typst can't attach labels to figures in "code mode"

#let body = [In @tealrect we can see an example of a teal rectangle with rounded corners. #lorem(10)
#parbreak()
#lorem(100)]

//custom wrapping function to modify the default layout
#let wrapc(fig, body, align: right) = {
  let boxed = box(fig, inset: (bottom: 0.3em, top: 0.3em)) //box with inset to add some more space
  wrap-content(boxed, align: align)[#body]
}

#wrapc(fig, body, align: bottom + left)
```

`align` can be changed to other `align` values such as "right", "left", "bottom + right", etc.

If you need TWO images to go with a block of text, there is also the `wrap-top-bottom` function you can use.

The GitHub repository mentioned in user108903's answer makes you manually divide the text around the image into two parts, while `wrap-it` adjusts to different layouts automatically.